# What does it mean to say that a vector is in the column space of another?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose we have that a matrix $A$, and a vector $y$. When we say that $y$ is in the column space of $A$, what does that mean exactly? Does it mean we have that $y = Ax$ for some vector x and that the system is consistent? Thanks.

Comment: It means that $y$ is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix $A$; this is equivalent to saying that $y=Ax$ for some $x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statements mean exactly the same thing:

- $y$ is in the column space of $A$
- If $\vec a_1,\dots,\vec a_n$ are the columns of $A$, then there are some scalars $x_1,\dots,x_n$ (that is, a column-vector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$) for which $y = x_1 \vec a_1 + \cdots + x_n \vec a_n$
- For some vector $x$, we have $Ax = y$
- The system $Ax = y$ (where $y$ is the column-vector $y = (y_1,\dots,y_m)$) has a solution $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for some choice of values $x_1,\dots,x_n$
- The system $Ax = y$ is consistent

Hopefully that clears things up.